# Getting (lldb) output and hang on runtime

Tags: c++, xcode, combinations, lldb, factorial

I have a simple program that is calculating factorials, permutations and combinations. I feel good about my math but for whatever reason I cannot get this program to execute. Full disclosure I am new student to C++. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int factorial(int);
int permutations(int, int);
int combinations (int ,int);
void perms_and_combs(int, int, int&, int&);
int numPerms;
int numCombs;
int main() {
int factorialVal;
cout << "enter an int!\n";
cin >> factorialVal;
cout << "The factorial of " << factorialVal << " is " << factorial(factorialVal) << endl;
int permVal1;
int permVal2;
do {
    cout << "Input a two values: ";
    cin >> permVal1;
    cout << ", ";
    cin >> permVal2;
} while ( permVal1 < 0 || permVal2 > permVal1);
cout << "test"; // This line doesn't get executed
perms_and_combs(permVal1, permVal2, numPerms, numCombs);
cout << "Number of permutations: "<<numPerms << ". Number of combinations: " << numCombs;
return 0;
}

int factorial(int n) {
int product = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    product *= i;
}
return product;

}

int permutations (int n, int k) {

int result;
int denominator = n-k;
cout << denominator;
result = (factorial(n)/factorial(denominator));
return result;
}
int combinations (int n, int k) {
int result;
result = permutations(n, k) * (1/factorial(k));
return result;
}
void perms_and_combs(int n, int k, int& numPerms, int& numCombs) {
numPerms = permutations(n, k);
numCombs = combinations(n, k);
return;
}
```

Comment: How are you launching your program under LLDB?